# Graph website navigation Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, graph-visualization, arbor.js

I have three levels on my Web Site. At present, the navigation is about:

```
First : 1  : 90: (link)
             95: 281: (link)
                 139: (link)
        2  : (link)
        3  : 12: 124: (link)
        4  : (link)

Second: 5  : (link)
Others..
```

The best example I found to achieve what I wanted to, was the main page of http://arborjs.org/ : Immediately, only the first level is visible, then when you move hover your mouse, the next level pops up.
But it has good performances only on Chrome, and it doesn't work on other browsers..

The amount of data isn't a lot ( at most 4^3 nodes ), but I can't find any solution woking enough well

Comment: yes, for example, every nodes has 4 child, at the third level are 4^3

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this could be done similar to a drop down menu via css3. I couldn't find any css3 implementation for a directed graph, but I did find the following libraries in JavaScript.

- [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery): D3.js is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data. D3 helps you bring data to life using HTML, SVG and CSS. D3’s emphasis on web standards gives you the full capabilities of modern browsers without tying yourself to a proprietary framework, combining powerful visualization components and a data-driven approach to DOM manipulation.
- [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/): Processing.js is the sister project of the popular Processing visual programming language, designed for the web. Processing.js makes your data visualizations, digital art, interactive animations, educational graphs, video games, etc. work using web standards and without any plug-ins. You write code using the Processing language, include it in your web page, and Processing.js does the rest. It's not magic, but almost.